# 2012 Ford Escape with Flex Fuel capabilities

Tags: ford, fuel-system, escape

Can Regular gas (not containing ethanol) be used in a 2012 Ford Escape with Flex Fuel capabilities?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

In a word: **Absolutely**.

There's no reason not to be able to use full fledged petrol. In order to be flex fuel capable, it has to know how much ethanol is in the system and adjust accordingly. It will know you have little to no ethanol in the system, which will allow it to make the changes to keep it running right.